# Scroll the controls over using JDesktopPane in Swing

Tags: java, swing, scroll, jscrollpane, jdesktoppane

I have designed swing controls over JPanel using netbeans , now i want the control should scroll with the click on Jscrollbar or JSlider

```
Suppose i have four buttons on the jpanel from then they should appear one by one from  
right to left while clicking on the jscrollbar or jslider.
```

Comment: what happened when you tried it?

Comment: actually i want to make scrolling as the single screen should scroll in a single click on scrolling on left side or right side

Comment: Your intent is not clear. Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows what you've tried. A simple diagram might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [JComponent.scrollRectToVisible](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#scrollRectToVisible%28java.awt.Rectangle%29).